# Docker compose volume

Tags: docker

i have build a docker image that contains multiple configuration files inside the docker container. Now i want to write a docker compose file that uses this docker image and maps the configuration file into the host system.
The reason:
I want to be able to configure the configuration files with the host system without accessing the container.

How can i do that?
I tried to define a volume inside the compose file. But if i start the container, it creates the directory on the host system. But the directory is empty. The mapped volume insider the container is not empty.

Best regards

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile` for creating the image and the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: The linked question describes a workaround to use Docker's "initialize a volume on first use" feature with a named volume that's actually a Linux bind mount.  You also might try distributing the user-editable configuration files outside the container, the same way you're distributing the `docker-compose.yml` file.